# React Redux --> UseSelector --> Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to make a simple exercise for react-redux to understand the process but somehow I am stuck .. any help would be really appreciate.

The interesting part is when I do subscribe and try to log store into the console, it works and shows me updated value but I am not able to select it using useSelector
Also with the help of Dev tool's i could see the state being changed from INIT to ADD_USER..

Below are my components files and reducers.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {  Provider } from "react-redux";
import  store from "./stores/store";
import { HomePage } from "./components/containers/HomePage";


function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <HomePage/>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

HomePage.js. --> Here state.isLogin is not selected.. but the subscribe comment works

```
import React from "react";
import { Sidebar } from "./Sidebar";
import { LoginPage } from "./LoginPage";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const HomePage = () => {
    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.isLogin);
 // const storeState = store.subscribe (() => console.log(store.getState()));

    return (
              <div>
                <LoginPage />
                <Sidebar />
            </div>

        );
};
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as action from "../../action/index";


export const LoginPage = (setLogin) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    const createUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const addUser = {
            name: name,
            isLogin: true
        };
        dispatch(action.addUsers(addUser));
    };

    return (
            <div className="card border-0 shadow">
                <div className="card-header">Login Here!</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => createUser(e)}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Create Contact
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};
```

reducers - Index.js and user.js

```
import userReducer from './users'

import { combineReducers} from "redux";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    addUser : userReducer,

});

export  default  allReducers;
```

User.js

```
import * as types from '../actionTypes/index'

const intialState = {
    user: [],
    messages : [],
    isLogin : false
};
const users = (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: [action.payload.name, ...state.user],
                isLogin: action.payload.isLogin
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default users;
```

Store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import allReducers from '../reducers'

const store = createStore(allReducers,composeWithDevTools());

export default store;
```

Any idea's/Input on what went wrong ? or what is the issue?

Thank you

Comment: do you have a root reducer file ? . can we see that code ? . What are you passing to the first argument of your createStore ?

Comment: Hey @Shyam, I have added the root reducer file and also the store.js file in the question. I am missing some syntax or conceptually something is wrong?

Comment: access your state as `const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.addUser.isLogin)` .

Comment: Wow!! It worked! I did try using that before but when I wrote addUser, IDE did not show anything and there was a grey line so i thought it would be an error and did not continue.. FML !! But thanks @Shyam!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code in HomePage

```
 const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.addUser.isLogin);
```